# How to get all related category listing from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to show all related category listing based on parent category.

Table **leh34_mt_cats**

```
cat_id    cat_name

100         Tours
101         Food
102         Fun
```

Table **leh34_mt_relcats**

```
cat_id    rel_id
100         85
100         86
100         89
101         92
101         93  


<?php
$qry2 = "SELECT * FROM `leh34_mt_cats` mt inner join leh34_mt_relcats rel on rel.rel_id = mt.cat_id where  rel.cat_id = (select cat_id from leh34_mt_cats where cat_name = 'Tours and Travels')";
$reg2 = mysql_query($qry2);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($reg2))
{?>
<li><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></li>
```

I just want to get cat_name from sql query, currently it's static.
Any help please..

Comment: you need a connection to database http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and use the connection in query $reg2 = mysql_query($qry2, $con)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT leh34_mt_cats.cat_id, leh34_mt_cats.cat_name, leh34_mt_relcats.rel_id
FROM leh34_mt_cats, leh34_mt_relcats
WHERE leh34_mt_cats.cat_id = leh34_mt_relcats.cat_id
```

It displays `cat_id` , `cat_name` and `rel_id`.

May be helpful